# Angular Dynamically loaded module needs to use root injector service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am loading module dynamically using system `JS` in `Angular 6` and using `angular-cli` very similar to below link.

([Load new modules dynamically in run-time with Angular CLI & Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5))

Dynamically loaded module creates it's child injector and create new instance of services rather than using services from root injector.

As per `Angular` doc, lazy loaded module creates its own child injector and instances of service. In order to avoid that (for singleton), they suggest to create `forRoot` static method in lazy loaded module and import it in app module.

But in my case, as I am loading module at run time, I can't import `LazyLoadedMOdule.forRoot()` at bootstrap. I get to know which module is going to get loaded only at run time.

Can you please suggest to keep services singleton and use it in dynamically loaded module ?

Answer (score 0):

For services that need to be singletons throughout the entire app, the recommended approach is to define those in a *core* module, which is then imported in the root module (`AppModule`).

You can refer to the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module) for more detailed information.

Comment: this can be done but problem here is that lazy loaded module always creates separate child injector with new service instance . only way to deal with it is import static method forRoot in main app which is not possible in my case

Comment: Make sure you are not re-registering those services inside your lazy-loaded module definition. In other words, they should be declared _only_ in the `providers` section of the core module.