# Angular App dynamically load plugin without recompile

Tags: angular, web-frontend, plugin-architecture, system.js

I'm trying to develop the frontend of my Web Api (NET CORE) pluginable application. I would like to use Angular 9 but im not an expert in angular.

My backend was designed to be extensible and at startup it watches in a specified folder and if exists one or more dll files that contains logic to extend base application (like a plugin) it loads them.
I want to use a similar approach in the frontend. I tried different solutions and read a lot of articles but is difficult to find somebody that want to import unknown plugin at compile time.

I tried lazy modules (starting from this: https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular/) that would be perfect but using this I have to know implemented plugin (modules) before compiling my angular app because if I want to use the modules I have to use Import function in my main app.

So I searched more and after the article [Load new modules dynamically in run-time with Angular CLI & Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5) I tried System.Js approach but I can't find a working solution for angular 9.

I'am pretty sure that I am not the only one that would create a pluginable Angular app that load plugins without recompile main app.

I need some suggest to the right approach to follow or a working example of an angular app that use plugins architecture.

Comment: A hotpluggable architecture for angular isn't widely achived yet. Only angular 9, with its imports during runtime, made it possible to build something like this without a hacky workaround.
Some resource: https://brianflove.com/2019/12/13/lazy-load-angular-v9-components/

Comment: @mamichels thanks for the interesting link. I find something usefull (I hope) for my solution in the comments when an user show the method 'loadModule(moduleInfo: ModuleData, ownerWindow?: any)' ... this gave me hope.

Comment: The URL mentioned by @mamichels seems to be changed to https://brianflove.com/2019-12-13/lazy-load-angular-v9-components/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the better and elegant solution because I'm a newbie in Angular but it works for me at the moment.

I assume that a plugin is an **Element Web Component** (https://angular.io/guide/elements).
To create my first Element (Plugin) I followed this tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-elements-web-components/.

By the way at this point I cant load my plugins dinamically because I have to know the component's name that I deployed in my element before compile the project to use it.
I found the solution using **Extensions Element** (https://angular-extensions.github.io/elements/#/home).
So I created a dynamic component that I use to show the plugin's component at runtime.

This is the code of the dynamic component:

```
export class DynamicComponentContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  plugin: Plugin
  sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pluginService: PluginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.pluginService.getPlugin(data['pluginName'])
            .subscribe(
              (res) => {
                this.plugin = res;
              },
              (err) => {
                console.error(err)
              } 
            );
          });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And its html template:

```
<div *ngIf="plugin != null">
<ng-template #loading>Loading plugin {{plugin.tag}} ...</ng-template>
<ng-template #error>Error Loading plugin {{plugin.tag}}</ng-template>
<ax-lazy-element
    *axLazyElementDynamic="plugin.tag; url: plugin.url; module: plugin.isModule; 
errorTemplate: error; loadingTemplate: loading;">
</ax-lazy-element>
</div>
```

It can works because my backend serves the plugin's JS compiled file (Element Web Component) so I had to register my plugin (because I need some values to handle it like the component's name or the route's path) before using it.
In fact, the **axLazyElementDynamic** attribute in the dynamic component need the url of the JS Element Web Component file and the component name to work.

Now I had to add dinamically the route paths to every plugin component.
In my App Component I created this simply method:

```
loadPlugins() {
  this.pluginService.getPlugins()
    .subscribe(plugins => {
      plugins.forEach(plugin => {
        this.router.config.unshift({ path: plugin.path, component: 
DynamicComponentContainerComponent, data: { pluginName: plugin.name } });
        this.links.push({ text: plugin.description, path: plugin.path });
      });
    });
}
```

The plugin service simply obtains plugins data from backend (where I registered plugins before).

I hope this can helps someone.